# Ensuring Systemd service using `User=` directive does not clean up after user logs out

Tags: systemd

### Details

We have a `systemd` service file with the following pertinent directives:
`Type=forking`
`User=me`
`Restart=always`

The `WantedBy` directive is currently not set.

We have a cron job that executes `su –l me –c '<some command>'`.

### Preconditions

We noticed that given:

- The service is started
- The user `me` is **not** logged into the system

### Observations

Everytime the cron job finishes executing, the System V IPC queues disappears and the service restarts since the processes reading/sleeping on the queues wake up to find the queues are gone and hence enter a failed state.

After the cron job finishes we noticed the following in the syslog:
`… systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID XXX`

### Possible Solution

We `installed` a file such that:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/logind.conf.d/my-service.conf
[Login]
KillUserProcesses=no
RemoveIPC=no
```

### Question

After reading [systemd changelog for changes with 230](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/e81f253/NEWS#L29), we are still confused if our Possible Solution mentioned above is enough.

We are confused in particular about the `additional steps are necessary to allow intentionally long-running processes to survive logout.`

The services parent as reported by `systemd-cgls` is `system.slice` so that makes us believe the prescribed step to start the service using `systemd-run` does not apply here - is this true? We are currently starting the service with `systemctl start my-service.service`

Would we still need to enable `lingering` for the user `me`?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't even need `KillUserProcesses=no`.  `RemoveIPC=no` should be sufficient.

Enabling lingering for the user `me` would be an alternative to that.  It would differ in that it would leave a `systemd --user` instance running all the time.

> This behavior is controlled by the KillUserProcesses=
>             setting in logind.conf, and the previous default of "no" is now
>             changed to "yes". This means that user sessions will be properly
>             cleaned up after, but additional steps are necessary to allow
>   intentionally long-running processes to survive logout.

What the quote means is that "additional steps" are necessary to allow e.g. GNU Screen to continue running after logout, if and only if KillUserProcesses=yes.  The additional steps are basically `systemd-run --user --scope COMMAND`, AND enabling lingering.

This is not related to your desire.  Because your service process does not run within a login session.

Your conclusion from looking at systemd-cgls is exactly correct.

---

An alternative would be to never log in as the user `me`.  `su` counts as a login.  User crontabs potentially count as a log in (unless /etc/pam.d/cron avoids invoking pam_systemd, directly or indirectly).  For example you can replace your use of `su` with `setpriv`, or instead of cron use a systemd timer unit which starts a oneshot service which has `User=me`.

Comment: Thanks for this. The command `loginctl enable-linger <user-id>` was enough to prevent systemd from cleaning up some symlinks to the host that were setup inside a container using a startup script.

Comment: Important to note that linger must be enabled for each user's session files you wish to retain. For example if you enable it for `alice`, systemd is still going to cleanup the session files for user `bob` and everyone else who's not `alice`